# Sound coming from both headphones and speakers on Lenovo G460

Tags: 10.04, sound, lenovo, headphones, speakers

I've installed Ubuntu 10.04 yesterday on Lenovo G460. I'm unable to fix this problem after lot of tries in changing model in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf to thinkpad/auto/lenovo and many things.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It appears that the new kernel did not correctly detect the sound card model that you have. You will have to edit the /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf file and set the model manually with

```
options snd-hda-intel model=<model>
```

Unfortunately, finding the correct sound card model can take a little guess work. I took me several tries to find the sound card model that would detect the headphones correctly.

This link gives a list of sound card model: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1043568

More information can be found on the Ubuntu Wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto

Answer (score 1):

I have something like this going on with my Sony VPCZ114GX, there is a workaround posted for my model at this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/960124
Basically involves loading up David Henninsson's hda-jack-retask from his ppa at  https://launchpad.net/~diwic/+archive/hda and then try Wouter van der Graaf's workaround on comment #7.

As for getting the model of your sound card, I tried the below. Although the problem may be that your machine doesn't know what model to use for sound in the first place.

$ `aplay -l`
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC889 Analog [ALC889 Analog]
...

Then to get the model to put in alsa-base.conf:
$ gunzip -c /usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz |grep -i "alc889"
  intel-alc889a Intel IbexPeak with ALC889A
  intel-x58 Intel DX58 with ALC889

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgraging to 12.04 on my Acer Extensa machine. Changing options of the `snd-hda-intel` module had no effect. After spending few hours by googling with no success I tried to look at the settings in alsamixer. And found that only one thing I had to do was enabling muting speakers at this Alsa mixer frontend.

So my solution was to launch `alsamixer` in console window and by using keyboard to enable this option. How easy....

Hope that help.

Updade: the exact name of the option is "Auto-Mute Mode"